# How to take 2 input value from a UITableViewCell in objective c

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit

I need to take 2 input value from the same `UITableViewCell` like textfield 1 and textfield 2 [score 1, score 2] and add these value in a dictionary and add these dictionary data to a `NSMutableArray`.

I tried this below code with the text field delegate method..

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *txtIndPath = [tblMonthlyPerformanceReport indexPathForCell:cell];
MonthlyPerformanceQuestions * question;
if (txtIndPath.section==0)
{
    question = [[HSEAppData appData].arrayMonthlyGeneralQustion objectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row];

}
if (txtIndPath.section==1)
{
    question = [[HSEAppData appData].arrayMonthlyLeadQustion objectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row];

} if (txtIndPath.section==2)
{
    question = [[HSEAppData appData].arrayMonthlyLagQustion objectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row];

}

NSLog(@"%@ , %@",question.QuestionId, question.Question);

NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[userDictionary setObject:question.QuestionId forKey:@"question"];
if (textField.tag==10001)
{
    [userDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"score1"];
}
if (textField.tag==10002)
{
[userDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"score2"];

}

[scoreMutableArray addObject:userDictionary];
```

i got the response

```
{
question = a5k0k0000004kxsAAA;
score2 = 5;
}
```

i put data on score 1 but data came on score 2 
i need the dictionary data like this

```
{
                "question": "a5k0k0000004kxnAAA", 
                "score1": "20", 
                "score2": "20"
            }
```

please help me

Comment: Instead of using `textFieldDidEndEditing` you should use `shouldChangeCharacters` after adding replacement string to the pre-existing text. As sometimes a bug appears if user presses some action to go to the next screen directly without dismissing the keyboard. 

Use a model instead of directly changing the dictionary keys (better practice) as string values maybe mistyped or change and just write a parser to directly convert it to and from from a `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Dictionary as global variable. Add each value in dictionary and then while adding dictionary to array check count of dictionary if it is 3 then add dictionary to array and after adding make dictionary empty.